# Why does my mapbox component (in Ionic app) work on browser/localhost but not when I bring it to my Android emulator?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mapbox-gl-js, capacitor, react-map-gl

Hi I'm making an ionic app and can't get my mapbox component to work on my android emulator despite working in the browser.  I tried to make a really simplified version of my mapbox component here:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';
import './studioMap.css';
import { IonPage, IonContent } from '@ionic/react';


export default function StudioMap() {

  let [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 37.7577,
    longitude: -122.4376,
    zoom: 8,
  });

  return (
      <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
      <ReactMapGL 
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/pobblebonk/cksjvglar47ri17pe8idxehk6"
        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
        {...viewport} 
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewport(viewport)}
      >
      </ReactMapGL>
      </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
  )
}
```

It has a really basic css file:

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

This is in my index.html file:

```
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<meta
      name="viewport"
      content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
```

All I get is a beige screen with the mapbox logo at the bottom left.  Any idea why this doesn't work on the android emulator?

As a side note, when I don't have `width='100%' height='100%'` included the mapbox logo disappears and I'm just left with a beige screen.  I felt like I was getting closer once I added that but I still have no map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm i --save-dev worker-loader
```

then adding

```js
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax 
(mapboxgl as any).workerClass = require("worker-loader!mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp-worker").default;
```

worked for me